# Access a file from a web service

Tags: java, xml, web-services, file-io, glassfish

I am using netbeans to create a web service and using Glassfish as the server to test it within netbeans.

I have a file that i wish the web service to be able to read data from and possibly write to it. But where do i put the file. If 'course' is my netbeans project root i have tried placing the file in the following locations:

```
\Course
\Course\xml-resources\jaxb\FlightRequest
\Course\web
\Course\web\WEB-INF
\Course\src\java\org\me\FBooking
\Course\build\web
\Course\build\web\WEB-INF
\Course\build\web\WEB-INF\classes
```

and tried accessing it in the web service in my unmarshalling code using (as the file i am trying to access is an xml document):

```
un = (AvailableFlights) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new java.io.File("AvailableFlights.xml"));
```

But it cant find the file

So where am i supposed to place it?

Comment: If you only need to read from the file, put it under src/main/resources (maven's standard location for application resources). Make sure your ide copies files under src/main/resources to the compilers output folder (WEB-INF/classes for a webapp)

Comment: I have placed the file in: \Course\build\web\WEB-INF\classes But i still cant access it.

I also tried making the web service write a file to find the default location it saves to and it appears to be :

C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\

But i guess this wouldnt be a practical location to use if i was to deploy this web service

Answer (score 0):

If you need to write to the file, you should locate the file outside of your deployable code.

If you only need read-only access, putting the file in web/ will make the file accessible from a web browser. That may not be what you want.

If you put the file under WEB-INF/classes, it will be accessible to your code, but not publicly exposed.

Your code fragment for accessing the file will only work for files on the file system, and not for files you deploy as part of the WAR, so you need to look into other ways of loading the file if you decide to package it as part of your WAR.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("file")
```

which should be able to read from files within a WAR file. (Haven't tested it right now..) But this is only for reading from the file.